# Table content is not getting rendered symmetrically in pdf-XSLT

Tags: xslt-2.0, xsl-fo, xslt-3.0

I am writing a simple table with two columns; but when it is getting rendered I am seeing it is getting rendered asymmetrical ; attaching screen shot

[image: Asymmetric rendering]

Below is my simple table code sample:

```
<xsl:template name="Header">

   <fo:table table-layout="fixed" width="100%">

    <fo:table-column column-width="proportional-column-width(1.2)" border-style="solid"/>
    <fo:table-column column-width="proportional-column-width(2)" border-style="solid"/>

     <fo:table-body>
       <fo:table-row>
         <fo:table-cell column-number="1">
          <fo:block font-size="3.5mm">
           <xsl:value-of select="xpath/get/element-val"/>
          </fo:block>
         </fo:table-cell>

         <fo:table-cell column-number="2">
          <fo:block font-size="3.5mm">
           <xsl:value-of select="xpath/get/element-val"/>
          </fo:block>
         </fo:table-cell>
       </fo:table-row>
     </fo:table-body>
   </fo:table>

</xsl:template>
```

I am not trying any thing fancy here; and the content that is getting rendered in second column is what I am looking for both the columns; tried to add padding but not working.

**Update**

Had tried display-align="after" but nothing fruitful.

**Further update**

Below is the flow only for calling the template

```
<xsl:template name="Details">

 <fo:block font-size="4.3mm" space-after.precedence="force" space-after="-3.5mm">
   Testimonial is. 
   <fo:leader leader-pattern="rule" alignment-baseline="before-edge" rule-thickness=".5mm" leader-length="255.4mm" color="cmyk(0,0,0,1)"/>
 </fo:block>
  <!--Here page available width is 255.4 only-->
   <xsl:call-template name="Temp2"/>
   <xsl:call-template name="Header">
  <!--had share template Header already-->
 </xsl:template>
 
  <xsl:template name="Temp2">

  <fo:table table-layout="fixed" width="100%">

    <fo:table-column column-width="33mm"/>
    <fo:table-column column-width="proportional-column-width(1)"/>

    <fo:table-body>

    <fo:table-row>
     <xsl:for-each select="xpath/get/element-val">
      <xsl:if test=".='D'">
        <fo:table-cell column-number="1">
          <fo:block>
           <fo:inline font-size="3.4mm" text-decoration="underline" writing-mode="lr">
             <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::*[1]"/>
           </fo:inline>
          </fo:block>
         </fo:table-cell>
      </xsl:if>
     </xsl:for-each>

     <xsl:for-each select="xpath/get/element-val">
      <xsl:if test=".='E'">
        <fo:table-cell column-number="2">
         <fo:block font-size="3.4mm" writing-mode="lr" padding-top="1mm">
           <xsl:value-of select="concat(.,' ',following-sibling::*[1])"/>
          </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
      </xsl:if>
     </xsl:for-each>
    </fo:table-row>

   </fo:table-body>

  </fo:table>

</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Can you add the actual XSL-FO markup that's produced? I don't see the cause of your problem, but you've also obviously simplified a few things in your XSLT.

Comment: @TonyGraham i had added the template calls in the question; yes that is what I am saying I am not doing any thing fancy here. Calling with very simple fo: attributes only.

Comment: Ok I figure out the problem I was calling this table inside a for-each and hence it was utilizing 1st row 1st column and second row second column which was causing the issue; we can close this.

Comment: "we can close this" - What do you mean by that? If you have a solution, post an answer. And when asking a question, make sure to provide a [mcve].